# Is the version problem a nightmare in programming?

Tags: version-control, versioning

Let say you are building an app and you are using the latest library verion from a third party (say `ver2.jar`). Then you saw an example written 2 years ago, but that example uses the `ver1.jar`

Now in `ver1.jar`, there is `web.method1()`, but in `ver2.jar` there is no such method. Instead, in `ver2.jar` you have `web.getOtherMethod.method1();`

You ran your app with `ver2.jar` and found a lot of missing classes, and lots of errors. So what are you going to do to solve the incompatibility?

I think the version problem is really a nightmare because it is unstructured and you do not actually understand what is going on.

Also, why changed the location of the method in `ver2.jar` so differently like that?

Comment: First, it may only appear unstructured to you. Next, I may be indeed unstructured regarding the particular change you are talking about, because of the people who did that one in an less cleverly manner. However, this is not the case in general. Compatibility requires doing one's homework, that's for sure, but it is not that hard either. In most cases, once you thought about it and established a few simple rules, it just works.

Comment: u seee this is Apache said "+) commons-codec-1.3 does not contain the DecoderException
+) if it is not found you may have a look at earlier releases to fix the 
problem" (from a blog) Why we have to look for the eariler version to fix the problem? it is very nightmare actually

Comment: If we could anticipate all changes we make to our code, we would just write it perfect in the first place. Code gets maintained and the API changes between major versions, that's simply how it is. If you want to get with the new functionality, you'll have to learn how the new version works. All together it is very unclear what you're asking: do you want to know about the concept of the adapter pattern or is this just a rant?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a question of versioning or verison control -- this is a question of amaturish interface design.  In proper, professional utility code design, you never "make a new version" of the interface that's entirely incompatible with the old one, espcially without providing a compatability layer.

In the example you provided, the `web` interface contained in the `ver1.jar` file has a method like follows:

```
interface web {
   void method1()
}
```

Once this is published and provided for public use, it is **amaturish** to ever, ever, ever break it.  Usually, the developers will define an additional interface, possibly with a back-reference to the old way of doing things

```
interface web2 {
    web getOtherMethod()
}
interface oldStuff {
   void method1()
}
```

It also wouldn't be improper to add additional methods to an existing interface:

```
interface web {
   void method1()
   void method2()
}
```

But if a simple version change breaks code you wrote against a library, it's either not a library worth using, or you were attemping to write directly to the internals instead of the interface.

---

For further reading on Java and interfaces, there are [basic tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) available for Java, and it's not to hard to find a seasoned programmer to extol the virtues of interfaces and encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to protect yourself when using 3rd party libraries. One such method is to use the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). This way you can use your class and keep it relatively the same in your code base and make any changes necessary with the library in your adapter class. It will also make unit testing much easier to verify version changes since you just need to test your adapter class rather than your entire code base to ensure that any changes in upgrading the library doesn't impact anything else.